# Incorrect DateTime minutes every now and then?

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a mobile/web application that stores chat messages in a MySql database. I just noticed that at times, the minutes are incorrect by just a few (minus 3-4 minutes) on select messages?

For example, I did a few entries in rapid succession and these were my results:

```
ID     DATETME
581    2016-12-14 15:32:47
580    2016-12-14 15:36:23
579    2016-12-14 15:36:21
578    2016-12-14 15:36:19
577    2016-12-14 15:32:39
576    2016-12-14 15:36:15
```

Please not that it is not due to async issues as I have confirmed that they are indeed inserted in the right order by means of a message add to each message. It is just the time that has a life of its own and jumps back and forth?

My system is hosted on AWS.

Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: Is your datetime automatically set in the DB by SQL DEFAULT(getdate()) or do you set it manually with C#?

Comment: Maybe you are in distributed server, and petitions are computing in different machines.

Comment: Well, yes, I have HA running with two machines, but 3-4 minutes apart? Is that logical?

Comment: Yes that is logical if your machines' times are noit synched over the network.

Comment: Any ideas on how to get them synced?

Comment: How about using triggers in your table? so you don't set it in your application but it's inserted by the mysql if you create a new entry in table. So you always have the datetime of your server... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: It was the sync issue. Turns out the clock on one of the machines was a few minutes behind, and I guess the load balancer sent me to different machines at times. Turns out this can happen when you upload new versions of the app. I am now grabbing the datetime from the database server instead, works fine.